# How to make js function show random numbers rather than count

Tags: javascript

How can I change the following function so it will display random numbers instead of counting up to the final number?

```
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
  $({
    countNum: $this.text()
  }).animate({
    countNum: countTo
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function() {
      $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function() {
      $this.text(this.countNum);
      var element = document.getElementById('result');
      element.style.opacity = "1";
      element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=1)'; // IE fallback

      var button = document.getElementById('return');
      button.style.opacity = "1";
      button.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=1)'; // IE fallback

    }
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
step: function() {
    $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
},
```

Should be:

```
step: function() {
    var min = 5; // change min if you want to
    var max = 200; // change max if you want to
    $this.text(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)); // use Math.random to generate the random numbers
},
```

Comment: Thanks very much, just what I wanted! :)

Comment: You're welcome! Your code needs a bit of tidying though!

Comment: @Patrick never mind I just thought that the first two parameters of `animate` is no longer necessary.

Comment: ahh okay! Thanks for your help anyways, really appreciate it!